# Run method in computation expressions

Tags: f#

What's the status of the `Run()` method in a computation method? I've seen it in several examples ([here](http://tomasp.net/articles/imperative-ii-break.aspx), [here](http://stevehorsfield.wordpress.com/2009/09/11/f-pipelined-monads/), [here](http://techneilogy.blogspot.com/2010/09/f-computation-expressions-yieldfor.html)), and I've seen in it F#'s compiler source, yet it's not in the [spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html) or the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182.aspx). I filed an [issue in MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/606300/incomplete-msdn-page-about-computation-expressions-f) about this and it was closed as "by design" without further explanations.

So is it deprecated/undocumented/unsupported? Should I avoid it?

**UPDATE**: MS Connect issue status was promptly changed and the MSDN page updated to include Run()

Comment: In the case of my blog, I'm a relative newcomer to F#. My uses of advanced concepts like Run() may not necessarily represent best practices. I tend to explore odd and atypical uses for language constructs when I'm just learning them, lol.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

6.3.10 Computation Expressions

> More specifically, computation
>   expressions are of the form
>   builder-expr { cexpr } where cexpr is,
>   syntactically, the grammar of
>   expressions with the additional
>   constructs defined in comp-expr.
>   Computation expressions are used for
>   sequences and other non-standard
>   interpretations of the F# expression
>   syntax. The expression builder-expr {
>   cexpr } translates to

```
let b = builder-expr in b.Run (b.Delay(fun () -> {| cexpr |}C))
```

> for a fresh variable b. If no method Run exists on the inferred type of b when this 
>   expression is checked, then that call is omitted. Likewise, if no method Delay exists on > the type of b when this expression is checked, then that call is omitted

Answer (score 4):

I think that the `Run` method was added quite late in the development process, so that's probably a reason why it is missing in the documentation. As desco explains, the method is used to "run" a computation expression. This means that whenever you write `expr { ... }`, the translated code will be wrapped in a call to `Run`.

The method is a bit problematic, because it breaks compositionality. For example, it is sensible to require that for any computation expression, the following two examples represents the same thing:

```
expr { let! a = foo()           expr { let! c = expr {  
       let! b = bar(a)                   let! a = foo()
       let! c = woo(b)                   let! b = bar(a) 
       return! zoo(c) }                  return! woo(b) }
                                       return! zoo(c) }
```

However, the `Run` method will be called only on the overall result in the left example and two times on the right (for the overall computation expression and for the nested one). A usual type signature of the method is `M<T> -> T`, which means that the right code will not even compile.

For this reason, it is a good idea to avoid it when creating *monads* (as they are usually defined and used e.g. in Haskell), because the `Run` method breaks some nice aspects of monads. However, if you know what you are doing, then it can be useful...

For example, in my `break` code, the computation builder executes its body immediately (in the declaration), so adding `Run` to unwrap the result doesn't break compositionality - composing means just running another code. However, defining `Run` for `async` and other delayed computations is not a good idea at all.

Comment: hmm, this is worrying... I'm actually using it to *enable* compositionality (code: http://github.com/mausch/FsSql/blob/938b55f7e057e95d10de2cca6f4f2679c870cc2e/FsSql/Transactions.fs#L120 )

Comment: @Mauricio: I don't fully understand your code, but one important difference is that your `Run` has a type `M<T> -> M<T>` - the cases that break compatibility usually have something like `M<T> -> T` (e.g. when computaiton builder creates a task and starts it).